# animation in PopupControlExtender

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I want to add an animation to PopupControlExtender .... so , what is the Animations that we can put 
in PopupControlExtender...?::

i download this code ...

html code:

```
<html>
<head >
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <br />
        ToDo:
        <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" Width="538px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="popupControl">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Width="146px">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Scott Guthrie"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Simon Muzio"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Brian Goldfarb"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Joe Stagner"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Shawn Nandi"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
    &nbsp;
    <br />
    <ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="MyTextBox" PopupControlID="Panel1" CommitProperty="value" CommitScript="e.value += ' - SEND A MEETING REQUEST!';" Position="Bottom">
    </ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender>

    </div>
    </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

vb code:

Imports AjaxControlToolkit

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged

        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue)) Then
            PopupControlExtender.GetProxyForCurrentPopup(Me.Page).Commit(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue)
        End If
        RadioButtonList1.ClearSelection()
    End Sub
End Class
```

can't i just put it like this

for example...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at this

- [PopupControlExtender Animation
  examples](http://forums.asp.net/t/1232644.aspx)
- [Using Animations with the
  PopupControlExtender](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2007/08/10/using-animations-with-the-popupcontrolextender.aspx)
- [Using Animations](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/UsingAnimations.aspx)

Comment: i used •PopupControlExtender Animation examples , and it gave me
:::
 Animation on TargetControlID="Button1" uses property AjaxControlToolkit.PopupControlExtender.OnHide that does not exist or cannot be set